# meteor.js errors/debugging unreadable

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

EDIT:
I guess the codes are color codes (as seen in bash)
Also it might be intersting that I am using Babel to transpile ES6 to ES5

---

I am not sure how to ask the question to get the correct answer from google or Stackoverflow. I am sure this has been asked before somewhere. So if anybody has a link please post it here so this could be marked as duplicate or just answer right here ;)

In meteor when there is an error I get really awkward formatted errors.
Here's what the errors look like:
(as you can see this is not really helpful due to the broken encoding?? or what is the issue here?)

```
App running at: http://localhost:3000/
=> Client modified -- refreshing (x10)
Errors prevented startup:

While building package XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.es6: Unexpected token (144:37)
  142 |   onCreate[34m[1m([22m[39m[34m[1m)[22m[39m [32m{[39m
  143 |     console[1m.[22mlog[34m[1m([22m[39m[36mthis[39m[34m[1m)[22m[39m[1m;[22m
> 144 |     [36mvar[39m clickEvent [1m=[22m [36mnew[39m ReactiveVar[34m[1m([22m[39m[36mreturn[39m [34m[1m([22m[39m[34m[1m)[22m[39m[1m=>[22m[32m{[39mconsole[1m.[22mlog[34m[1m([22m[39m[36mreturn[39m[31m'foo'[39m[34m[1m)[22m[39m[32m}[39m[34m[1m)[22m[39m[1m;[22m
      |                                      ^
  145 |   [32m}[39m
  146 | 
  147 |   template[34m[1m([22m[39m[34m[1m)[22m[39m [32m{[39m

Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: Is this in a package you wrote? Usually it means there is a syntax error in the code at the specified line number.

Comment: @Xinzz The error is not important. I am talking about the `[34m[1m` stuff (I guess they are color codes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your question is

- "how do I turn off the [erroneous] terminal codes in Meteor"

Meteor detects if the output is going to a terminal and format it without the fancy codes if it is not a terminal -- for example like when is writing to a log file.

You are not mentioning what system you are using, but on my system (Linux) redirecting the output changes the behavior so I get different output in the case of

```
meteor run | cat
```

compared to the usual

```
meteor run
```

Comment: This helped a lot. thx. It was in fact terminal errors that were malformed in the browser.. duh.. stupid me..